# Find items in the array based on the inner array condition

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

How to find id in an array that is inside of an array of objects

Example:

```
let arrayobjects = [{ 
    id: 1, 
    name: "oinoin", 
    description: ["one", "two", "three"]
}, { 
    id: 2, 
    name: "zatata", 
    description: ["four", "five", "six"]
}];
```

How can I find the id of the word "two" ?

Comment: Please put some effort into your question! Include a [mcve] of what you have tried to solve the problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need more than one item, you can filter the array via [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), check if property  `description` for each item contains word `two` via [**Array#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) **(ES7)**, then map the result to get only `id` of those items using [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let arrayobjects = [
      { id: 1, name: "oinoin", description: ["one", "two", "three"] }, 
      { id: 2, name: "zatata", description: ["four", "five", "six"] }
];

const ids = arrayobjects.filter(item => item.description.includes('two'))
                        .map(item => item.id);
                        
console.log(ids);
```

If you have only one item, you can just use [**Array#find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and do same checking

```js
let arrayobjects = [
      { id: 1, name: "oinoin", description: ["one", "two", "three"] }, 
      { id: 2, name: "zatata", description: ["four", "five", "six"] }
];

const item = arrayobjects.find(item => item.description.includes('two'));
                        
console.log(item.id);
```

Comment: He could use `find` instead of `filter`, which seems more suited (same code, different output)

Comment: Note: Not IE11 compatible

Comment: `find` returns first item only, maybe there are more than one item

Comment: @SurenSrapyan that's an assumption, in this case there is only one item

Comment: @trichetriche So why not assume ? Updated for two solutions

Comment: @SurenSrapyan because If I were to assume, I would assume this is only an example and that he actually wants to return the `name` property. Do you see how problematic it is ?

Comment: He says that only id ) So your assumption is not correct

Comment: Yeah but I assume it's an exemple and he actually wants `name`, the same way you assume there is several items and not just one. You must rely on the code provided to provide an answer, not on assumptions.

Comment: @MilanVelebit Development is changed. There are many tools that will make it work in older browsers. So it is not a problem.

Comment: Hey guys this works for me! This returns me an array of ids founded with the given word! Works like a charm. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

This snippet might be what you are looking for

`arrayobjects.filter( ele => ele.description.includes("two")).map(ele => ele.id)`

output :`[1]`

Answer (score 1):

There may be more efficient way, but i some how find a solution. iterate through the array and match the array item.

```js
var arrayobjects = [{ id: 1, name: "oinoin", description: ["one", "two", "three"]}, { id: 2, name: "zatata", description: ["four", "five", "six"]}];
arrayobjects.forEach(item => {
  if(item.description.indexOf('two') != -1 ){
  console.log(item.id)
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) too

```
arrayobjects.filter(f=>f.description.indexOf('two')>-1)[0].id
```

```js
let arrayobjects = [
{ 
    id: 1, 
    name: "oinoin", 
    description: ["one", "two", "three"]
}, { 
    id: 2, 
    name: "zatata", 
    description: ["four", "five", "six"]
}
];

console.log(arrayobjects.filter(f=>f.description.indexOf('two')>-1)[0].id);
```

**Note**

`.filter` returns an array. So if multiple items are found with `two` in description then you do not use index `[0]`. This is just an example of one item in array.

Answer (score 0):

For examples sake, here is a version with old javascript.

```js
  var arrayobjects = [
    { 
        id: 1, 
        name: "oinoin", 
        description: ["one", "two", "three"]
    }, { 
        id: 2, 
        name: "zatata", 
        description: ["four", "five", "six"]
    }
  ];

  function findId (desc, arr) {
    var idx, arrObjLen = arr.length, results = [];

    // Iterate through the first array
    for (idx = 0; idx < arrObjLen; idx ++) {
      // If the value exists in the 'description' array
      if (arr[idx].description.indexOf(desc) > -1) {
        // Add it to the results array
        results.push(arr[idx].id)
      }
    }
    return results;
  }

  console.log('Results:', findId('five', arrayobjects));
```

You could also use `Array#reduce` if you want to minimise the amount of code you're using:

```js
const arrayobjects = [
    { 
        id: 1, 
        name: "oinoin", 
        description: ["one", "two", "three"]
    }, { 
        id: 2, 
        name: "zatata", 
        description: ["four", "five", "six"]
    }
  ];

console.log(

  arrayobjects.reduce((col, { id, description }) => 
    // If description contains the desired value
    description.includes('two')
      // Add the id to the collector array
      ? [ ...col, id ] : col, [])

);
```